# TTL high input, outcome?

Tags: ttl

My books states that when a TTL input is high, the emitter diode cuts off and the emitter current is approximately zero. This animation shows that when a transistor input is high, the emitter diode isn't cut off. https://youtu.be/7ukDKVHnac4?t=327

Comment: Instead of linking in a video, add a screenshot or draw the schematic.

Comment: That video is not discussing the TTL configuration at all. The books are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the video is showing a configuration where the emitter of an NPN transistor is grounded, and the transistor turn on when a positive base voltage is applied.

The TTL book you mentioned is probably talking about an open emitter configuration, with the emitter being the input and the base connected to a positive supply voltage, through a resistor.  In that case, the emitter needs to be grounded (or taken low) in order to turn on the transistor.

This picture from TI's "Designing With Logic" book 1997, shows a typical open-emitter input stage for a TTL device.

[image]

**EDIT 1 - Let Me Try**

Let's focus on Q1.  The base of Q1 is tied to Vcc (+5V in these devices) through R1.  Forget about the collector of Q1 for now.

Think about these two questions:

1. What happens to Q1 if the emitter is left open?  Is Q1 turned ON or OFF (ignoring secondary affects like leakage)?
2. With this circuit, how would you turn Q1 ON?  What does the emitter have to be connected to, or what voltage needs to be applied to the emitter in order for Q1 to turn ON - to start to conduct?

Comment: Why does the emitter need to be grounded (or taken low) in order to turn on the transistor, wouldn't that turn off the transitor, because it needs the base and the emitter both turned on to overcome the barrier potential?

Comment: @Road, the BJT is "on" when \$V_b - V_e > 0.6 V\$. In this circuit we do that by lowering the emitter voltage rather than raising the base voltage.

Comment: @ThePhoton, why does lowering the emitter voltage raise the voltage?

Comment: @Road, if \$x=x_1-x_2\$, what would you expect lowering \$x_2\$ to do to \$x\$?

Comment: @ThePhoton, x would raise. If the base of the NPN transistor has a voltage of 0.4V and the emitter a voltage of 0.4V, the NP base diode will be forward biased, and the voltage of the emitter would turn on the transistor, however when the emitter has a voltage of 0V, the voltage wouldn't be high enough to overcome the barrier potential?

Comment: @Road, in your circuit,  the base of Q1 is tied to VCC, which is much higher than 0.4 V.